# Rails4: how to restrict streaming video files access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, video-streaming, html5-video, assets

I would like to put some html5 videos inside my page, but the access to this video can be given only to logged in users (so non-logged in users must not see the video, also if they have the url):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/video.m4v" type="video/m4v">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I tried with something like this in my action (with a before filter for access restriction):

```
  def video
    respond_to do |format|
      format.m4v{
        send_data File.join([Rails.root, "public", "videos", "sample.m4v"]), type: 'video/m4v', disposition: :inline
      }
      format.mp4{
        send_data File.join([Rails.root, "public", "videos", "sample.mp4"]), type: 'video/mp4', disposition: :inline
      }
    end
  end
```

but this is sending the file as an attachment, and not just serving it.

Is it possible? and, if yes, how can it be done?

thank you

Comment: Are you using an authentication solution like Devise?

Comment: you did the right thing with disposition. Maybe yet another turbolink issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818015/rails-wont-send-data-as-file

Comment: @ekremkrc Yes i'm using Devise for authentication.

Comment: @apneadiving doesn't seem a turbolink issue, i'm not using anchors. Even though i tried to disable them, but it's not working anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this is working, i was missing an option, that is :stream => true. With that videos are served the right way.

```
send_file File.join([Rails.root, "private/videos", @lesson.link_video1 + ".#{extension}"]), 
      :disposition => :inline, :stream => true
```

The problem now is another one, that i asked here

[Rails serving large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099856/rails-serving-large-files)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to use `video_tag` to render the video as part of a view?

If so, just use the devise helper `user_signed_in?` in the ERB file you'd like the video to display in. This makes sure only signed in users can see the video in the `video_tag`.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= video_tag ['/video.mp4', '/video.m4v'], controls: true, height: '240', width: '320' %>
<% end %>
```

For more information on `video_tag`, see:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#linking-to-videos-with-the-video-tag

Comment: Well the videos are already served in a protected page, visible only to logged users. The problem is that i need to protect the resource from who knows the url, that's why i'm doing this way.

Comment: Oh I see. That definitely seems less straight-forward. Would this stackoverflow answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14306165/2856441